# Using Fonts from the Fourier LaTeX Package in MATLAB's Plots

Tags: matlab

I'm using the `fourier` package to make my $\LaTeX$ documents look pretty, but they would be even prettier if I could mimic the same font in legends, axis labels etc. in my Matlab plots.

I know there are ways to find-and-replace texts in eps graphics within $\TeX$, but that would require me to specify all the labels in the .tex file as well, which I'd like to avoid if I can.

It's mostly just simple letters - no complicated math markup or anything - so just rendering alphabetical characters in the correct font would be sufficient.

I have tried for example

```
l = legend(planetNames); % PlanetNames is a cell array with strings
set(l, 'FontName', 'utopia'); % Tried Utopia as well with same result
```

but instead of the Utopia font, I get some ugly, monospaced placeholder font. How do I make this work?

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, Matlab 7.12.0 (R2011a) and TeX Live 2009.

Comment: I'm thinking http://tex.stackexchange.com would be more suited to questions about LaTeX.

Comment: [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) is the right place to ask this sort of questions.

Comment: @Tomas: After I [migrated your question to TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51216), I saw your comment, and I've reopened the question here, because (as you point out) the question is about doing something in Matlab. This is one of the rare occasions where I am in favor of having the same question on multiple sites - in particular, I feel that your question is much more likely to get an answer on TeX.SE. I let the TeX.SE moderators know what I did and we'll see what happens.

Comment: No TeX.SE isn't really the right place to ask how to get fonts into Matlab, even if they are LaTeX fonts. Some software related site would fit better. http://superusers.com maybe? (I'm one of the TeX.SE moderators, btw.)

Comment: @Zev, Thomas: Whether or not TeX.SE is the right place or not is irrelevant to the fact that math.SE is *not* the right place for this question.

Comment: @Asaf: I don't think it's so clear either way. The FAQ states that we accept questions about software that mathematicians use, but also that typesetting questions are off-topic. I feel like this question falls more on the side of being a Matlab question than a typesetting question (I guess I think of typesetting as being specifically for a paper). However, I don't really have such strong feelings about it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I agree that this might not be on-topic here - and I don't mind being migrated if there is somewhere this question is more likely to get an answer. However, even though StackOverflow might really be a match here, I'm afraid this question concerns languages and features that won't be used by most users there, so the question will likely drown in all the talk about Java, Ruby, Python and C#... Posting at math.stackexchange.net was an attempt to find a smaller niche where people will actually know what I'm talking about :P And I do think this site is a better match than tex, btw.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB comes with its own packages of TeX packages.
You can add to them external packages.

Hence, your only choice is to approach MathWorks and ask for a feature to be added.